# Select multiple contacts in Flutter

Tags: flutter, contacts

So, I thought that I would try Flutter for my next cross-platform app, since it offers the bonus of also being runnable in the browser (with Hummingbird).

Two major things it needs to be able to do are selecting multiple contacts and getting the device's 'phone number (default SIM card if there are multiple).

It seems like selecting multiple contacts is going to require jumping through hoops. In fact, all that I can find is [this](https://medium.com/flutterpub/flutter-multiple-contacts-selection-using-two-plugins-a-custom-code-4b5b5a27c6b8), which requires two plugins.

Is there any simpler way?

Comment: I don't think you need `simple_permissions` plugin for that, you can stick to just `contacts_service`

Comment: Can you check `contact_picker` bit outdated and currently inactive but if it solves your purpose you can contribute to maintaining that plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this plugin
[fluttercontactpicker](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttercontactpicker)

```
final EmailContact contact =
          await FlutterContactPicker.pickEmailContact();
```

Comment: UPDATE: The above plugin doesn't support iOS. So you can use this plugin instead.     https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_contact_picker